# Spring MVC - log every incoming http request call with payload into database

Tags: spring-mvc

experts, I would log  every incoming http request call with payload into database.
I checked there would be 2 approaches.
use filter or  interceptor.
I feel filter is so easier for me to implement.
what would be best approach for my purpose?
please kindly advise.
thank you very much!

Comment: you can go with interceptor,  In Spring Context it will be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

if you have a need to do something completely generic (e.g. log all requests), then a filter is sufficient - but if the behavior depends on the target handler or you want to do something between the request handling and view rendering, then the HandlerInterceptor provides that flexibility.

But anyway, just do the way which make you feel easily and simply.

Note:

- Interceptor work in spring application context
- Servlet work in web context

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring AOP. Use any advice according to your needs.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Test {


@Around("@annotation(mapping)  ")
public Object preAuthUserPersmission(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RequestMapping mapping) throws Throwable {

Object[] parameters = joinPoint.getArgs();
 // Your actions on the input parameters
    return joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
 }
}
```